# How to associate data to a ListView item?

Tags: c#, .net, listview, winapi

In Windows API, I can use the `lParam` memeber of the `LVITEM` structure to associate data to a ListView item. Can I do a similar thing in C#?

**Note:** Of course I can just add an extra column to my ListView to do that, but I don't want to display this data to the user.

Comment: Far better is to use virtual mode and avoid using your UI control as a data structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Tag` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.tag), which can store an arbitrary object.